# OpenVPN fails to start due to options error in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have followed the guide here https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openvpn.html but when i try to start OpenVPN i get following error:

```
ovpn-server[2455]: Options error: --server and --server-bridge cannot be used together
```

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates you cannot use both server and server bridging together you need to choose one.

Comment: i dont exactly understand where/how i can modify this parameter?

Comment: In your configuration file /etc/openvpn/server.conf